# When I build unity app as standalone, all the shaders freak out? Glitching multicolor?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok Im building for Oculus Rift with Unity, and everything is fine, no performance or any problems in editor. When I build as a standalone with these build settings, however:

[image]

The standalone opens with this instead of the normal materials I have set up from unity - everything is glitching in multicolor:

[image]

Some work but most are the glitching. I have no idea what is happening here - everything else performance wise is great. How can I fix this? Im on 2018.2

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the Player.log file?

Comment: Have you tried adding your shaders to the "Always included shaders" list under Project settings > Graphics > Always included shaders? If it is a loading error this may fix it.

Comment: @remy_rm no that wasn't it - I explicitly added all the shaders in my scene, and besides Im 90% only using the Standard shader

Comment: @skyguy Check your GPU card settings, I had an issue like this at one point and it was a graphic card setting change that fixed it.  NVidia has a graphic card setting console that runs in the task bar.  I would recommend changing the settings to factory settings/default settings and see if that helps then change each setting one by one.